# Como puedo almacenar datos desde un formulario a un array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, loops

Buenas quisiera que ayuden con este sencillo formulario, se trata de que pueda capturar 3 números desde el form, que los pueda almacenar en un vector y que los muestre con otra función mostrar. No logro hacer que me guarde los datos, solo me los repite. Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia para trabajar con este tipo de datos?

```
<input type="text" id="numero1">
<input type="text" id="numero2">
<input type="text" id="numero3">
<input type="button" value="Capturar" onclick="Capturar()">
<input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar()">   

savearray = [];
var Capturar = function(){
    var array = [];                                 
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {               
        array[i] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero"+(i+1)).value);
        savearray.push (array[i]);  
        }
    }                       
var Mostrar = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < savearray.length; i++) {                    
        document.write (savearray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso veo más eficiente asigarnle la misma clase a todos los inputs, para cuando lo llames con [getElementsByClassName()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) te retornará un arreglo de los inputs, y con el podrás guardarlos desde sus propiedad de values.

```js
var Capturar = function(){
        let lstNumero = document.getElementsByClassName("numero"),
            arrayGuardar = [];         
        for (var i = 0; i < lstNumero.length; i++) {    
            arrayGuardar[i] = lstNumero[i].value;
            console.log (lstNumero[i].value);     
            }       
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="numero">
    <input type="text" class="numero">
    <input type="text" class="numero">
    <input type="button" value="Capturar" onclick="Capturar()">
```

Comment: de hecho si esta solo con el fomrulario ya te agrega un objeto con su key y su value y no hay que hacer un for

Comment: Ya pude solucionar lo del guardado, veo a este codigo lo puedo implementar. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tener un solo array y en él guardar los números de tu formulario. Por ejemplo:

```
var array = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    array[i] = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numero"+(i+1)).value);
 }

 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i]);//Aquí puedes procesar cada valor del array
 }
```

El array va a tener 3 valores (en las posiciones 0, 1 y 2), cada uno de ellos corresponde a cada valor de los campos numero1, numero2 y numero3 de tu formulario.

Comment: Al reemplazar "numero"+(i+1)).value -me da error- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: ¿Cuantos inputs tenés y que id tienen?

Comment: Tengo 3  <input type="text" id="numero1">
  <input type="text" id="numero2">
  <input type="text" id="numero3">

Comment: Entonces, no tenés porque tener un problema. Revisa bien el for, debe iterar sólo 3 treces (i = 0, i < 3,...).

Comment: Me sigue dando error si lo pongo fuera del parentesis en la consola me sale 3 Nan undefined

Comment: ¿Podes editar tu pregunta agregando el código que estás probando ahora?

Comment: Ya lo he editado

Comment: Revisa bien mi respuesta. Fijate que en tu código tenes ("numero1")+(i+1) y debe ser ("numero"+(i+1)). Además, dentro del for sólo tenés que asignar solo una vez el valor para array[i], y no tres veces como estas haciendo. Saludos!

Comment: Bien ya quedo editado, me muestra los valores gracias, pero ahora quisiera que me los guardara en cada ingreso y me los muestre en otra función.